# convert lists of uniform dicts into pandas Dataframe with nested dicts as multi-index

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

At a bit of loss despite much searching & experimentation...
Given this:

```
dictA = {'order': '1',
         'char': {'glyph': 'A',
                  'case': 'upper',
                  'vowel': True}
         }
dictB = {'order': '2',
         'char': {'glyph': 'B',
                  'case': 'upper',
                  'vowel': False}
         }
dictC = {'order': '3',
         'char': {'glyph': 'C',
                  'case': 'upper',
                  'vowel': False}
         }
dictD = {'order': '4',
         'char': {'glyph': 'd',
                  'case': 'lower',
                  'vowel': False}
         }
dictE = {'order': '5',
         'char': {'glyph': 'e',
                  'case': 'lower',
                  'vowel': True}
         }
letters = [dictA, dictB, dictC, dictD, dictE]
```

how to turn `letters` into into this: (first column is index)

> ```
>    order              char 
>           glyph       case      vowel
> 0      1      A      upper       True
> 1      2      B      upper      False
> 2      3      C      upper      False
> 3      4      d      lower      False
> 4      5      e      lower       True
> ```

... and as a plus, then be able operate on this frame to tally/plot number of entries that are uppercase, number of entries that are vowels, etc.

Any ideas?

EDIT:  My initial example was maybe too simple, but I'll leave it for posterity.

Given:

```
import re

class Glyph(dict):

    def __init__(self, glyph):
        super(Glyph, self).__init__()
        order = ord(glyph)
        self['glyph'] = glyph
        self['order'] = order
        kind = {'type': None}
        if re.search('\s+', glyph):
            kind = {'type': 'whitespace'}

        elif order in (range(ord('a'), ord('z')) +
                       range(ord('A'), ord('Z'))
                       ):

            lowercase = glyph.lower()
            kind = {
                'type': lowercase,
                'vowel': lowercase in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'],
                'case': ['upper', 'lower'][lowercase == glyph],
                'number': (ord(lowercase) - ord('a') + 1)
            }
        self['kind'] = kind

chars = [Glyph(x) for x in 'Hello World']
```

I can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(chars) # dataframe where 'order' & 'glyph' are OK...
# unpack 'kind' Series into list of dicts and use those to make a table 
kindDf = pd.DataFrame(data=[x for x in df['kind']])
```

My intuition would lead me to think I could then do this:

```
df['kind'] = kindDf
```

...But that only adds the first column of my kindDF and puts it under 'kind' in df.  Next attempt:

```
df.pop('kind') # get rid of this column of dicts
joined = df.join(kindDf)  # flattens 'kind'...
```

`joined` is *so close*!  The trouble is I want those columns from kind to be under a 'kind' hierarchy, rather than flat (as the `joined` result is).  I've tried stack/unstack magic, but I can't grasp it.  Do I need a MultiIndex?

Answer (score 1):

This gets you close on the first part:

```
## a list for storing properly formated dataframes
container=[]
for l in letters:

    ## loop through list of dicts, turn each into a dataframe
    ## then add `order` to the index. Then make the dataframe wide using unstack
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data=l).set_index('order',append=True).unstack(level=[0])
    container.append(temp)

## throw all the dataframes together into one
result = pd.concat(container).reset_index()
result

  order   char             
          case glyph  vowel
0     1  upper     A   True
1     2  upper     B  False
2     3  upper     C  False
3     4  lower     d  False
4     5  lower     e   True
```

For the second part, you can just rely on `groupby` and then the built in plotting functions for quick visuals. Omit the `plot` call after `size()` if you just want to see the tally.

```
result.groupby(result.char.vowel).size().plot(kind='bar',
       figsize=[8,6])
title('Glyphs are awesome')
```

[image]

Comment: This is still wizardry to me, but I guess I got the results I asked for.  Still having trouble understanding how to 'reframe' a column of dicts.

Comment: @RyandeKleer I added a few comments to the code. I use indexing and unstacking a lot for restructuring dataframes in general.

Comment: @RyandeKleer, was there any follow-up questions or was this resolved for you?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to revisit this yet.  I'd like to try playing with concat & unstack on my second example to see if this solution scales well.  Will let you know.

Comment: Oh. Just saw you edited the question. It appears rather materially different than the initial one now.

Comment: The core of the question was intended not to be a solution to a specific data set; rather how to merge nested data into a sub column, in general.  Should I rework the wording in the question, or maybe scrap the first example entirely?

Comment: Well either question is fine as far as they go, but for answering, it is a moving target. So if the underlying question changes, folks don't know what you are really asking. So I would generally close one and open another, and then you can say how the two are related, that one is more generic, or whatever the difference may be. But it is always a judgment call as to what is the same question, and what is different enough to warrant a separate question.

Comment: So, what does your target data look like?